# 5-операционный

Tags: орфография

"5-операционный"(пятиоперационный)- правильно ли написано слово с цифрой? Или 
нужно "5-ти операционный"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5-операционный.

Answer (score 0):

можно и "пятиоперационный", как четырёхквартирный, семиэтажный, двузначный...